# How can I hide sub-links of drop-down menu on mobile?

Tags: javascript, button, navigationbar, submenu

I have tweaked W3Schools' [responsive navbar with dropdown](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown.asp) for my local bowling club's [website](http://www.lauriestonbowlingclub.com/) which looks and works fine on pc and mobile.

With one exception - on mobile, sub-menus are initially hidden and then displayed when a button is clicked. What I would like to do is close them again when the same button is clicked. At present, this can only be achieved by clicking elsewhere on the screen.

I'm fairly new to programming (in particular Javascript) and have been unable to find a solution, therefore any help/suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 499px) {
  /* Set width of nav */
  nav {
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  /* Set width and style of primary container */
  .topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  /* Insert home icon */
  .topnav #homebutton {
    line-height: 3rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  /* Style primary and secondary <a> links */
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 3rem;
  }
  /* Set width and border of primary <a> links */
  .topnav>a {
    width: auto;
  }
  /* Set width of dropdown container */
  .dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 3rem;
  }
  /* Set width, border and style of primary dropdown buttons */
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 1rem;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 3rem;
    width: auto;
  }
  /* Hide and style secondary dropdown container */
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  /* Style secondary dropdown <a> links */
  .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 0 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 3rem;
  }
  /* Style primary links on hover */
  .topnav a:hover,
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #555;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  /* Style secondary links on hover */
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #000000;
  }
  /* Display secondary container */
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child),
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
      display: none;
    }
    .topnav a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
    .topnav.responsive {
      position: relative;
    }
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
      float: none;
    }
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
      position: relative;
    }
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  /* Set width of nav */
  nav {
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  /* Set width and style of primary container */
  .topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
  }
  /* Insert home icon */
  .topnav #homebutton {
    line-height: 3rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }
  /* Style primary and secondary <a> links */
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 3rem;
  }
  /* Set width and border of primary <a> links */
  .topnav>a {
    width: calc(14.28571428571429% - 1px);
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
  }
  /* Set width and border of penultimate primary <a> link */
  .topnav>a:nth-last-of-type(2) {
    width: 14.28571428571429%;
    border-right: 0;
  }
  /* Hide hamburger */
  .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
  }
  /* Set width of dropdown container */
  .dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 3rem;
    width: 14.28571428571429%;
  }
  /* Set width, border and style of primary dropdown buttons */
  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 1rem;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0 0;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 3rem;
    width: calc(100% - 1px);
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
  }
  /* Hide and style secondary dropdown container */
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    width: 14.28571428571429%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  /* Style secondary dropdown <a> links */
  .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 3rem;
  }
  /* Style primary links on hover */
  .topnav a:hover,
  .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #555;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  /* Style secondary links on hover */
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: #000000;
  }
  /* Display secondary container */
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">

    <a href="#" id="homebutton" class="fa fa-home">Item 1</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Item 2
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
   </button>
      <div class="#">
        <a href="#">Item 2.1</a>
        <a href="#">Item 2.2</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a href="#">Item 3</a>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;
</a>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example. Now you have to integrate the functions of my example into your example ... **But I'll leave that up to you :)**
If it doesn't work you can contact me or give me your real project to manage this problem!

```js
var showMenuText = $('#toggle').text();
var hideMenuText = 'Close';

$('#navigation ul').hide();
$('#navigation ul a.active+ul').show();

hideMenu = function() {
    $('#navigation ul#menu').hide();
    $('#navigation').removeClass('open');
    $('#toggle').text(showMenuText);
}

$('#toggle').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();
    $('#navigation ul#menu').toggle();
    $('#navigation').toggleClass('open');
    var toggleText = $('#toggle').text();
    (toggleText == showMenuText) ? $(this).text(hideMenuText) : $(this).text(showMenuText);
});

$('ul#menu > li > a').click(function(event){
    $this = $(this);
    if( $this.hasClass('page') ) parent.location = $this.attr('href');
    if( $this.hasClass('home') ) { parent.location = '/'; }

    event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();
    if( $this.hasClass('active') ) var justclosed = true;
    $('a.active').removeClass('active').next('ul').hide();
    if(!justclosed) $this.addClass('active').next('ul').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigation">
<p><a href="" id="toggle">Menu</a></p>

<ul id="menu">
 <li>
  <a href="testen.html" class="book-campaigns">Menu 1</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="testen.html" class="lol">lol</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="lol">lol2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="lol">lol</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="lol">lol2</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
    <a href="/#" class="book-campaigns">Menu 2</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="lol">lol</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="lol">lol2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="lol">lol</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="lol">lol2</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    
    <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Stack_Overflow_logo.png" class="book-campaigns">Stackoverflow</a>

    <li>
     <a href="/#" class="book-campaigns">Menu 3</a>
  <ul>
         <li><a href="#" class="lol">lol</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="lol">lol2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="lol">lol</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="lol">lol2</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Good succeed!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply and for suggesting a solution. Much appreciated. I will have a go at integrating the functions/code into my website and let you know how I get on. Once again, thanks for your help. Best wishes, Peter.

Comment: no problem and good results, I am available to answer any questions or ambiguities

Comment: Hi @SwissCodeMen,

I've integrated your functions into my code and the sub-menus now open and close when their parent list-item are clicked. So thanks once again for your help.

However, with regard to stand-alone list-items with no sub-menus (such as
`<li><a href="join.html" class="book-campaigns">Join</a></li>`), when I click their links nothing happens (ie I am not re-directed to their URLs).

Is this a result of your functions? Or perhaps an error on my part?

I would be grateful if you could assist.

Best wishes,
Peter

Comment: Hei @PeterAlexander. I'm glad it worked out so far... there's an implementation flaw in my code. This can be fixed by removing the <li> tag. I have adapted the above example and linked it to an image.
I hope your problem is now completely solved.

Comment: Thanks once again, @SwissCodeMen. I'll remove the <li> tags, modify my CSS styling and let you know how I got on.

Comment: Well, I'm excitedly waiting for the answer if it worked!

Comment: Yip, worked a treat. Just figuring out how to modify CSS style. Thanks again.

Comment: Super, that makes me happy.  good work! Is the website with the new function online?

Comment: here's a link to the website. Its fairly basic, but with programming not being my day job, it does the job. In time, I hope to add a horizontal drop down nav for laptops/tablets, but that's for another day. Thanks once again for your help. http://www.lauriestonbowlingclub.com/

Comment: but it looks really nice with the submenus. Well done. No problem, another time gladly again :)